# How to set default time for QML DatePicker?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

According to the [API](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components.Pickers.DatePicker/) I should use `date` property, but with `mode: "Hours|Minutes"` the picker stays at `00:00`. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to set a default value:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import Ubuntu.Components.Pickers 0.1

DatePicker {
    id: timePicker
    mode: "Hours|Minutes"
    date: new Date(0,0,0,8,5)
}
```

The Date object is used to work with dates and times.

Date objects are created with new Date().

There are four ways of instantiating a date:

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        DatePicker {
                    id: timePicker
                    mode: "Hours|Minutes"
                    date: {
                        var time = new Date()
                        time.setHours(8)
                        time.setMinutes(5)
                        return time
                    }
        }
```